# Difference between 遍 and 度/回 in occurences

Tags: usage, nuances, counters

I have known for a while about 度 and 回 when counting occurrences, but recently I found a passage that used 遍 as well, which surprised me.

> 一[遍]{ぺん}転べば・・・十[遍]{ぺん}転べば・・・百[遍]{ぺん}転べば・・・

If I understand correctly, 度 is used for degrees, 回 for revolutions, and 回 is more common for larger numbers.

However, where does 遍 fit into all of this? Is it more archaic? Is it more similar to 度 or 回?

Comment: Would you mind adding a little context, or telling us where it's from?  I googled and found something called さんねん峠.  Is that right?

Comment: This looks interesting: http://www.ritsumei.ac.jp/acd/cg/lt/rb/630/630PDF/tao.pdf

Comment: @snailboat Correct. That pdf looks interesting, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「遍」 is used to count action,movement or behavior.
and It is more archaic and informal than 「回」

○「その動画１０遍見たけど、理解出来なかった」

(I watched the video for 10times but I couldn't understand any of it.)

This word can't be used for Ordinal number.

×「この映画を見るのはこれが3遍目です。」

○「この動画を見るのはこれが3回目です。」

(This is third time for me to watch this video.)